# Benefit of 64 bit over 32 bit with QT and opengl

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, compiler-construction, qt5

Although searching for awhile, I can not find any clear answer of what benefits there is for compiling 64bit programs over 32 bit.  There are many questions I find on SO on how to compile for 32 or 64 bit, and some questions about the 64bit versions of opengl, but they do not address the base question of why.

From what I find, it is difficult to use the MinGW compiler for 64 bit as there doesnt seem to be an official release from QT.  Currently I use MinGW 32 bit for making a 3d opengl application that is heavily focused on speed with large sets of vertices (using VBO to handle it).  I assume I would switch to visual studio for windows releases, and maybe use unofficial releases of 64bit for other platforms.

Since I have yet to find an OS which the compiled 32 bit version does not work, but since the target deployment of my application will be primarily on high end computers in research environments, I am fine with releasing 64 bit versions.

If the code is the same, is there a distinct advantage to switching the compiler from 32 to 64 bit for an application using Qt 5 and OpenGL?

Comment: Too board. It can't be answered without measuring specific case.

But in general the 64-bit system has more registers and more efficient ABI (for instant, less rely on stack)

Comment: Do you have larger datasets that doesn't fit in 32 bits of virtual memory (in practice it's less since the OS needs space as well)? Is you platform native 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the native system is 64 bits.  As we are still working on the system we havent ran into an obvious lack of memory.  However, since we allow a user to open any 3d model, it can be viewed as us wanting to allow maximum number of vertices.  At that point we would probably run into other issues with displaying the content, but that is a bit off topic from this question.

Comment: Then why not just target the native platform, i.e. don't do anything. Unless you're planning to make your application cross-platform, in which case you don't have to do much anyway, just be careful to check that all resource allocations (not only memory) succeeds. Oh, and use platform independent types whenever possible, like `int64_t` for 64-bit integers, `int16_t` for 16-bit integers, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make sure your dependency libraries are compiled for 64-bit, but after that the advantages are primarily things like access to more RAM (4+gig in a single process) and possibly faster data access times (due to a larger word size).  The second one depends heavily on your data access patterns and on how much the predictive cache can help, so it's hard to know if it will help much.  For most random access patterns, it doesn't help in a measurable way, and it's typically outweighed by what you *do* with the data anyway.

For OpenGL, it won't really make much difference.